# postgresql + jpa + persistence.xml

Tags: postgresql, jpa, glassfish, persistence

I have a problem to use PostgreSQL with JPA.

When i try to execute my app on glassfish i got this error:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: no schema has been selected to create in
Error Code: 0
Call: CREATE TABLE CABINET (ID INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID))
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="CREATE TABLE CABINET (ID INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID))")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:895)
```

So how can i specify the schema for JPA so it can be able to use postgresql

note: i have added the postgresql maven dependancy:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
```

Please help me; Thank you

Comment: Per default it isn't necessary to set a schema. Did you set the `DatabaseName` in the Glassfish JDBC connection pool settings?

Comment: for sure yes, i am used working with jdbc pools in glassfish. i didnt face any problem with MS SQL Server or MySQL. But with postgresql it is not working

Answer (score 0):

The schema is specified with the "search_path" variable in postgres.

To solve your problem, you have 2 solutions:

Permanently add the search to the user used by your connection:

```
ALTER user username set search_path=yourschema ;
```

Add temporarly the search_path in the jdbc connection (which i find ugly)

```
   set search_path=yourschema;
```